# iOS - Get the version of MobileVLCKit programmatically

Tags: swift, version, vlc

I need to know the version of my MobileVLCKit.framework in iOS project.

But I got a '0' value after I called `VLCLibrary.version()` function, can anyone tell me how to get this information programmatically?

I am using XCode 6.4 and swift language.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, sorry I can't really help you :(  However I'd love to have some advice on how did you succeed in integrating MobileVLCKit with swift? Have you compiled the library, with which parameters, or have you used cocoapods?

Comment: Hi, I download the VLC source from: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html. And use this command to compile the source for the device: `./buildMobileVLCKit.sh`. Then import the `libMobileVLCKit.a` under `./build/Release-iphoneos/` into your swift project. And also don't forget to import other frameworks in your project (You can check the example project that downloaded from the link to know which frameworks you need).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solutions.

The version can use following method to get

```
VLCLibrary.sharedLibrary().version
```

And It will return a String value.